# Procedure delete join entre tabelas

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Boa tarde, tenho o seguinte ambiente Tb.Cliente onde um cliente tem N processos na Tb.Processo, N andamentos na Tb.Andamento e N anexos na Tb.Anexo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso montar uma instrução sql que ao deletar um cliente pelo código "`ClienteID`", delete todos processos, andamentos e anexos vinculados.
Sendo que as Tb.Andamento e Tb.Anexo são vinculadas a Tb.Processo pelo "`NumeroProcesso`"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_Cliente

    @ClienteID int

AS
BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM Andamento WHERE NumeroProcesso IN         
        (SELECT NumeroProcesso FROM Processo WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID)
        SELECT * FROM Anexo WHERE NumeroProcesso IN         
        (SELECT NumeroProcesso FROM Processo WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID)
        SELECT * FROM ArquivoAnexoAcordo WHERE NumeroProcesso IN        
        (SELECT NumeroProcesso FROM Processo WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID)
        SELECT * FROM HistoricoNegociacao WHERE NumeroProcesso IN       
        (SELECT NumeroProcesso FROM Processo WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID)

        SELECT * FROM Cliente WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID
        SELECT * FROM Processo WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID


        DELETE Andamento WHERE NumeroProcesso IN                
        (SELECT NumeroProcesso FROM Processo WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID)
        DELETE Anexo WHERE NumeroProcesso IN                
        (SELECT NumeroProcesso FROM Processo WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID)
        DELETE ArquivoAnexoAcordo WHERE NumeroProcesso IN               
        (SELECT NumeroProcesso FROM Processo WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID)
        DELETE HistoricoNegociacao WHERE NumeroProcesso IN              
        (SELECT NumeroProcesso FROM Processo WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID)

        DELETE Processo WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID
        DELETE Cliente WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evandro o único problema que eu vi realmente grave na sua rotina é que não tem uma transação, ou seja, se ocorrer um erro em um das etapas, as anteriores não será desfeita.

Incluí uma transação e fiz uma melhoria nas queries para com um parâmetro e não uma subquery. No mais, acho que funcionará

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE delete_Cliente

    @ClienteID int

   AS
   BEGIN

    Declare @NumProcesso varchar(50)

    SELECT @NumProcesso = NumeroProcesso FROM Processo WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

            DELETE ArquivoAnexoAcordo WHERE NumeroProcesso = @NumProcesso               
            DELETE HistoricoNegociacao WHERE NumeroProcesso = @NumProcesso
            DELETE Andamento WHERE NumeroProcesso = @NumProcesso
            DELETE Anexo WHERE NumeroProcesso = @NumProcesso

            DELETE Processo WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID
            DELETE Cliente WHERE ClienteID = @ClienteID

    Commit transaction

    IF @@Error > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        PRINT 'ERRO AO EXCLUIR CLIENTE'

    END

   END
```

Comment: perfeito! obrigado pelas instruções

Comment: Observe que um cliente pode ter mais de um processo. Deve ser por isso que no código original do @Evandro havia uma subconsulta para cada DELETE.

Comment: Realmente, se existir mais de um processo deve ser feito um subselect ou Join

Answer (score 0):

Se um cliente pode ter mais de um processo, então é necessário ficar atento a esse detalhe. A sugestão que segue primeiro anota todos os processos do cliente para somente após ir apagando as linhas das tabelas.

```
-- código #1
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_Cliente
     @ClienteID int as
begin

-- anota todos os processos do cliente
declare @Processos_Cliente table (NumeroProcesso int primary key);

INSERT into @Processos_Cliente
  SELECT NumeroProcesso
    from Processo
    where ClienteID = @ClienteID;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- apaga andamento
DELETE Andamento 
  where NumeroProcesso in (SELECT NumeroProcesso from @Processos_Cliente);

-- apaga anexo
DELETE Anexo
  where NumeroProcesso in (SELECT NumeroProcesso from @Processos_Cliente);

-- apaga linha(s) do processo
DELETE Processo
  where NumeroProcesso in (SELECT NumeroProcesso from @Processos_Cliente);

-- apaga linha do cliente
DELETE Cliente
  where ClienteID = @ClienteID;

COMMIT;

end;
go
```

No código #1 constam as tabelas Cliente, Processo, Andamento e Anexo, que são as descritas no diagrama.